# Factor of 2 discrepancy in electric field on the surface of a uniformly charged spherical shell

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I recently came across this topic in electrostatics and saw derivations using Gauß's law of how the electric field on the surface of a uniformly charged shell is:

$$|\vec E|=\frac1{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac q{r^2}$$

This was mentioned in many sources including my school textbook. However, upon digging deeper, I found [this source](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/023/11/1215-1223) specifying the result to be

$$|\vec E|=\frac1{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac q{2r^2}$$

i.e. half of what was given before. I still don't understand what is the reason behind this disagreement.

Comment: Give us the reference links to at least the latter result. Preferably both. We need to see what the reasoning was.

Comment: https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/023/11/1215-1223#:~:text=“Thus%20the%20field%20at%20the,surface%20should%20be%20kQ%2FR2.  this is one of the articles which specifies it to be the latter one

Comment: https://www.shaalaa.com/question-bank-solutions/obtain-the-expression-for-electric-field-due-to-an-uniformly-charged-spherical-shell-electric-field-and-electric-field-lines_224331.   this is one of the many articles which suggest the former one

Comment: You should edit your question and put your paper link inside the question itself. However, I found that your link is written rather well and I fully understood it to be correct and rigorous and nice. What is it that you do not understand of it? It is simply the case that Gauß's law can only give you the field inside and outside the surface, and not exactly on the surface. The paper provided a good calculation and showed that it is half. And since the surface charge limit is a limit from ignoring that actual distributions have non-zero widths, this is physically pleasing too.

Comment: Also, note that this is extreme nit-picking. Basically nobody cares about the electric field precisely at the surface, which is why so many textbooks get it wrong. We are far more likely to care about the behaviour inside and outside, rather than precisely in the middle.

Comment: oh I see, basically I was initially confused about the two different answers. I too was  In much more agreement with the latter answer, however so many sources with a different view caused trouble. thanks for your help.